# Resolve "Class is not compatible with Class<T>"

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea

I'm using in a Java-Project a Framework (Ashley).
To use it I often have to write something like that:

```
entityEngine.getSystem(RenderingSystem.class).setProcessing(true);
```

While RenderingSystem is something Ive created, getSystem is an Part of the Framework itselve. Viewing the implementation of that method it looks like that:

```
 /**
 * Quick {@link EntitySystem} retrieval.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends EntitySystem> T getSystem(Class<T> systemType) {
    return systemManager.getSystem(systemType);
}
```

Now, even when I can compile and run the code with gradle, my IDE (IntelliJ) shows errors with the following warning:

[image]

What did I wrong, or how can I suppress these kind of warnings at least?

### EDIT

Here is the definition of my class "RenderingSystem":

```
public class RenderingSystem extends EntitySystem {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method accept class of type `T` which is `T extends EntitySystem>`

Your `RenderingSystem` have to extend `EntitySystem` (or implement if `EntitySystem` is an interface) to be compatible to that method

Comment: But its already extending that. This cant be the solution.
`public class RenderingSystem extends EntitySystem {...}`

Comment: But you are posting AnimationSystem

Comment: Yeah sorry, its my fault. But its the same for RenderingSystem.

Comment: You're importing wrong class for sure. Check the `RenderingSystem` to see if it extends the correct class

Comment: Ive just checked it. Its not extending the wrong class. Could be the problem the JDK version or something like that?

Comment: Prepare github or teamview. I"ll see

Answer (score 0):

> While RenderingSystem is something Ive created, getSystem is an Part
>   of the Framework itselve. Viewing the implementation of that method it
>   looks like that:

If you pass a `RenderingSystem` class you defined in your own project and that you cannot pass it to the `getSystem()` methods, it means that `RenderingSystem`  doesn't derive from `EntitySystem`.
You should probably extend/implement the `EntitySystem` class of the framework to make the `getSystem()` method usable with your own classes passed as parameter.

Comment: Same as I comment to @mạnh-quyết-nguyễn s anwer, my Systems already extends EntitySystem. So this can't be the solution. `public class RenderingSystem extends EntitySystem {...}`

Comment: Are you sure that the class extends `EntitySystem`  defined by the framework and not in your own project ?

Comment: jep, definitely. I've just double checked it.

Comment: Hmmm. In this case, I would advise to do a plain compilation with Gradle without IDE and to provide in your question the exact compilation error message. IDEs enjoy customizing error compilation messages.

Comment: I've already wrote it in the question: There are absolutly now error messages when running and/or compiling the program with gradle. These messages only shows within IntelliJ

Comment: Just to make this clear: I've still using gradle for compiling and running ON the bash. I want IntelliJ while developing. So I have to fix that error message since it confusing and distracting me while writing (not compiling/running) code.

Comment: I didn't ask you to not use IntelliJ to develop. I asked to provide the exact compilation error messaged provided by javac.

Comment: okay, sry for missunderstanding you. How can I force that output? Ive tried `./gradlew desktop:run --stacktrace` (where desktop:run is the task which compiles and runs my project)